# Tornado Sockets PHP/MySql Dialog Confirmation

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, jquery-ui-dialog, tornado

I am creating an application that uses a combination of Tornado Web Server and Symfony.

The tornado part uses sockets and queries a database every 1000ms and checks to see if it is different than what is currently stored in the cache (sort of like redis or memcache)

If there is anything different in the key value pair then it triggers a javascript query to deliver new information to the symfony application and triggers a jquery ui dialog to say "Hey it's your turn" and then waits for input from the user to change the mysql database and then it starts the whole process again and sends the "Somethings Changed" message to the other user.

The issue that I am having is sometimes the dialog does not trigger because it is receiving a "Somethings Changed" message that is blank.

I think what is happening is because Symfony and Tornado are both manipulating the database the "Somethings Changed" message is firing before the dialog pops up in the Symfony App

What I am trying to do is figure out a way to know if a specific jquery dialog has been opened during an update and if it has not been opened send a message to update again.

One idea is to do a database update in Tornado with a random number then when the dialog opens set that cookie to that random number. If the cookie matches the database entry then that means the proper dialog has been seen. If it does not match then trigger the push update again.

Am I way off base here? Is this theory even close to the way to do it?

This is the last part of my application and it works 8 to 9 times out of 10

ANY ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated